# VirtualBoxとvagrantを使って仮想マシンを立ち上げたい

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

[ローカル開発環境の構築 [macOS編] - プログラミングならドットインストール](https://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_localdev_mac_v2)

上記ページを参照して#06の「[仮想マシンを立ち上げよう](https://dotinstall.com/lessons/basic_localdev_mac_v2/38506)」まで進んだのですが、以下のエラーが出てしまいます。どうすればエラーを解消できるでしょうか。

**実行環境:**
Virtualbox 6.0.6
vagrant 2.2.4

**エラーメッセージ:**

```
~/MyVagrant/MyCentOS$ vagrant up
No usable default provider could be found for your system.

Vagrant relies on interactions with 3rd party systems, known as
"providers", to provide Vagrant with resources to run development
environments. Examples are VirtualBox, VMware, Hyper-V.

The easiest solution to this message is to install VirtualBox, which
is available for free on all major platforms.

If you believe you already have a provider available, make sure it
is properly installed and configured. You can see more details about
why a particular provider isn't working by forcing usage with
`vagrant up --provider=PROVIDER`, which should give you a more specific
error message for that particular provider.
```

Comment: host osは何を利用していますか？

Comment: 参考にしているページを見る限りは macOS でしょうか。

Comment: VirtualBox自身は(Vagrantを使用せずに)単独で正しく起動するでしょうか。VirtualBoxを再インストールしても症状は変わらないでしょうか。(私の環境では同じバージョンの組み合わせで問題なく動いていますし、vagrantのissuesにもそういった話は挙がっていないので、バージョン間の相性、というわけでは無さそうに思われます。)

Comment: 皆さん、ご協力ありがとうございます。
Vagrantfileを編集したところ、うまくエラーを解消できました。
https://qiita.com/miraidenshi/items/e2a2b3195a6c8e4bd5a7

Answer (score 0):

ちょっと古い(2016年7月)Qiitaの記事ですが、[【Mac】vagrant upでエラー](https://qiita.com/mtake6212/items/de7b26da8b283213f12a)　で説明されている症状に似ています。
ひょっとすると記事にかかれた対処方法で問題が解決するかもしれません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
僕の場合は、Vagrantfileを編集したところ、うまく問題が解決しました。

Answer (score -4):

VirtualBoxとvagrantの相性に問題はなかったです。
Vagrantfileを編集すると、エラーがなくなりました。
参考にした記事などをQiitaにアップしたのでぜひ見てください。
https://qiita.com/miraidenshi/items/e2a2b3195a6c8e4bd5a7

Comment: Vagrantfileのどこに問題があったか、また、どう直すことでエラーがなくなったかを記載していただければ、同じような問題に悩んでいる方の参考になる情報になると思います。